# Hyōgai kanji usage

Tags: kanji

Is it 'compulsory' that I can't use 蛸 in the word たこ焼き for 'octopus' and what would happen if I used it in a sign in Japan? Would police direct me to remove it?

For 外人, nothing specific is told about what happens to people who use Hyōgai kanji, or kanji outside of what's 'permitted' by the government.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what gave you the impression hyougai kanji are banned?

Comment: I'd guess I'm reacting emotionally to having restrictions placed on me by authority. I'm on the autistic spectrum, and some Japanese teachers are concerned about doing the same as everyone else. I'm much older than my teacher - but a rebel at heart.
Over decades, I notice lists of kanji, where some are no longer 'allowed' to be used for personal names. Perhaps it's about what is taught in school, or in newspapers etc. and what isn't.
Are these just 'suggestions' then, and not 'rules'. One Japanese woman said she had to have washing on the line by 11am or neighbours would look down on her!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost no Japanese people strictly remember which is a jōyō-kanji and which is not. Many hyōgai kanji are used by native speakers without even realizing it's so (e.g., 絆, 飴, 雫...). Of course, the police won't care, either.

Newspapers tend to follow the rule of not using hyōgai-kanji relatively strictly, but even newspaper publishers have their own lists of exceptional characters that are hyōgai but usable in articles.

That said, the spelling of *takoyaki* seen on signboards, Wikipedia articles and such is almost always たこ焼き (and rarely タコ焼き). If you used 蛸焼き, it would look simply unfamiliar, and some people might even wonder if you're selling something unusual.

Answer (score 2):

What is (almost) regulated is mostly publishing, like books and magazines. The government punishes nobody for using rare kanji, but publishers tend to have in-house rules that are based on the government's recommendations, with different levels of internal enforcement.

Newspapers tend to be strict about that. Lenient publishers might just warn the author and ultimately let what they want to do, if the author persists. Publishers and authors are perfectly fine to do so.

That is just this non-expert's impression. For professional assessment, see https://kotobaken.jp/qa/yokuaru/qa-119/ (in Japanese).

Comment: Thanks to people responding to my question. I just noticed the answers - as I'm visually impaired and forgot to scroll down further.

 I didn't really think police would step in. I'm concerned with Japanese youth suicide and restriction placed on people who can't 'conform' to expectations.

I quit my Japanese language class when I wrote this question. Perhaps the native language and cultural misunderstandings are a problem. The previous non-Japanese teacher understood my medical situation. I got a high grade, doing the test late in the day.
日本語の先生は私の個別の状況を理解できず、形式を変えてしまいました。

Comment: What I wrote is very pertinent to the kanji question. I have disabilities relating to remembering what people have said. I have a good visual memory though. I use mnemonics. Kanji is good for this, as it has meaning.
If there is only hiragana, I don't see where one word begins or ends. It's like English with no spaces between the words.
Japanese scripts are excellent to break up a sentence visually to make sense. The oral class didn't use kanji - as Chinese students in class see the kanji's meaning - yet can't pronounce it.
As I see kanji, Japanese words/sounds will come after the meaning.